# jQuery traversal of HTML using .parent() instead of .closest()

Tags: jquery, parent, children

Here is my simplified HTML:

```html
<html>
<body>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div id="link1">
    <a href="http://example.com?this=the+one+i+want">foo</a>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td>
   <div id="link2">
    <a href="http://example.com?this=bar">bar</a>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td>
   <div id="link3">
    <a href="http://example.com?this=baz" class="baz_anchor">baz</a>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div id="link1">
    <a href="http://example.com?this=foo">foo</a>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td>
   <div id="link2">
    <a href="http://example.com?this=bar">bar</a>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td>
   <div id="link3">
    <a href="http://example.com?this=qux" class="baz_anchor">qux</a>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.upstate.edu/assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My jQuery is below. I'm working with two anchors contained in separate TD elements which sort of look like they are on the same structural level, but are not actually DOM sibling nodes. It seems I can't use .closest() or .siblings() with this HTML and used a chain of .parent() and .children() instead. Is there a better way to do this?

```js
link = $('a.baz_anchor:contains("baz")').parent().parent().parent().children().children('div#link1').children('a').attr('href');
alert(link);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of shurtcuts can be taken here:

1. Chain of parents can be substituted by single `closest`
2. `find` looks through all layers of descendants, so a single selector can do for all `children`

All in all:

```
$('a.baz_anchor:contains("baz")').closest('tr')
                                 .find('div#link1 a')
                                 .attr('href')
```

By the way, most of that is redundant if you really look up div by id, as in `div#link1`. Id is supposed to be unique on the page, so if this is really the case, all you need is just `$('#link1 a').attr('href')`

Comment: Andrei, thank you! This is exactly what I wanted to know. I thought there must be jquery functions to do this. BTW, the actual HTML I am working with has repeating TR with DIV elements and - believe it or not - the DIVs do not use unique Id attributes. With these repeating ids the only unique value I can match on for my target row is the "baz" text. Sorry my HTML snippet didn't show that I was trying to keep it short.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis, I can believe that, of course. In practice identical ids behave fine mostly. However when they misbehave this is not always easy to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want to do.

Since **IDs are designed to be UNIQUE** you may not need to use either of the methods `.closest()`, `.parents()`, `.children` etc, if your goal is to select the `a` in `#link3`. This is all you need:

```
var link = $('#link1 > a').attr('href');
```

```js
console.log( $('#link1 > a').attr('href') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div id="link1">
    <a href="http://example.com?this=the+one+i+want">foo</a>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td>
   <div id="link2">
    <a href="http://example.com?this=bar">bar</a>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td>
   <div id="link3">
    <a href="http://example.com?this=baz" class="baz_anchor">baz</a>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

However if you want the `href` values for both elements, you can use the following which will give you an array:

```
var links = $('#link1 > a, #link3 > a').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('href');
})
.get();
```

```js
var links = $('#link1 > a, #link3 > a').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('href');
})
.get();

console.log( links );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <div id="link1">
        <a href="http://example.com?this=the+one+i+want">foo</a>
       </div>
      </td>
      <td>
       <div id="link2">
        <a href="http://example.com?this=bar">bar</a>
       </div>
      </td>
      <td>
       <div id="link3">
        <a href="http://example.com?this=baz" class="baz_anchor">baz</a>
       </div>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: PeterKA, I updated by HTML snippet. The actual code I am working with has multiple rows and unfortunately does *not* use unique ID attrs on the various rows. Sorry I didn't make that clear in the original snippet.

Comment: Great! So, what is it you want to do with the two `a` elements? What's your goal?